# [DJANGO]: How to pass a Django form field value to a template form action?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form that asks for id number. Hence, when the user clicks on submit, that id number is passed as a parameter to the endpoint.

This URL  `path('verify/nin/', views.post_nin, name='post_nin')` contains the form and asks for the id number while I am submitting the data to this URL to

```
   path('nin/<str:nin>',
             views.nin_verification_vw, name="nin_verification")
```

So I expect to be redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/nin/15374020766 but instead it is redirecting me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/nin/%3Cinput%20type=%22text%22%20name=%22nin%22%20required%20id=%22id_nin%22%3E?nin=15374020766&csrfmiddlewaretoken=u5UmwDW4KRUIvYWXAa64J8g1dTPoJ3yDqtoCuKjboIE2TNxI3tPbjPmCK6FztVwW

How do I avoid the unnecessary parameters?

Here is my forms.py:

```
class NINPostForm(forms.Form):
    """Form for a user to verify NIN"""
    nin = forms.CharField(required=True, help_text='e.g. 123xxxxxxxx')

    # check if the nin is a valid one
    def clean_nin(self):
        nin = self.cleaned_data['nin']
        regex = re.compile("^[0-9]{11}$")
        if not regex.match(nin):
            raise forms.ValidationError("NIN is incorrect.")

        return nin
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def post_nin(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NINPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data['nin']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/verify/nin?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = NINPostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        # 'cd': cd,
    }
    return render(request, 'ninform.html', context)
```

And here is my HTML template:

```
<form action="{% url 'nin_verification' form.nin %}" method="POST">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: Weird, the code looks fine...the only thing I can think of is that the HTML5 spec says the `method` attribute of `<form>` tags should be lowercase, so try it with `method="post"` and see if that changes anything (I wouldn't expect it to, but crazier things have happened...)

Comment: `form.nin` is a form field, when you render it / it's string value is an input tag as you see in the url. How do you even end up at this page? Or is some other view rendering this form? From what I understand you should be getting an error like `TypeError: post_nin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nin'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first import `redirect` : `from django.shortcuts import redirect`

Change your view to :

```
<form action="{% url 'post_nin'  %}" method="POST">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

You were passing the whole field instead of a String by using `form.nin` in your form `action` you should use your `post_nin` view to parse the nin field so...

Change your view to :

```
def post_nin(request):
    submitted = False # Don't understand this part
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NINPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nin = form.cleaned_data['nin']
            return redirect('nin_verification', nin=nin)
    else:
        form = NINPostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'ninform.html', context)
```

`